# CertBot Installation: Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (91.189.95.83)

Tags: apt, package-management, certificates, letsencrypt

I'm trying to install CertBot to issue a let's encrypt certificate for a domain but on my Ubuntu Server 16.04 I get errors when I run

```
sudo apt install python-certbot-apache
```

I get the following error

```
Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (91.189.95.83). - connect (113: No route to host)
```

and here the full response:

```
Get:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 python3-zope.hookable amd64 4.0.4-4+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+1 [9,442 B]
Get:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 python3-zope.interface amd64 4.3.2-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+1 [90.3 kB]
Get:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 python3-zope.component all 4.3.0-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+3 [43.3 kB]
Ign:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu xenial/main i386 python3-certbot all 0.26.1-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+2
Ign:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu xenial/main i386 certbot all 0.26.1-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+2
Ign:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu xenial/main i386 python3-augeas all 0.5.0-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+1
Ign:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu xenial/main i386 python3-certbot-apache all 0.25.0-2+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+1
Ign:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu xenial/main i386 python-certbot-apache all 0.25.0-2+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+1
Err:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu xenial/main i386 python3-certbot all 0.26.1-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+2
  Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (91.189.95.83). - connect (113: No route to host)
Err:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu xenial/main i386 certbot all 0.26.1-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+2
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu xenial/main i386 python3-augeas all 0.5.0-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+1
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu xenial/main i386 python3-certbot-apache all 0.25.0-2+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+1
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu xenial/main i386 python-certbot-apache all 0.25.0-2+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+1
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Fetched 1,837 kB in 2s (742 kB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-certbot/python3-certbot_0.26.1-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+2_all.deb  Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (91.189.95.83). - connect (113: No route to host)

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-certbot/certbot_0.26.1-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+2_all.deb  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-augeas/python3-augeas_0.5.0-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+1_all.deb  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-certbot-apache/python3-certbot-apache_0.25.0-2+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+1_all.deb  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-certbot-apache/python-certbot-apache_0.25.0-2+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+1_all.deb  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I've run apt-get clean, apt-get update but I get always the same error.

Comment: "no route to host " is not an apt error. It's a networking error. Check your network connectivity. Try pinging that host. Fix your proxy settings, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I get connection refused error

```
Err:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 python3-certbot-nginx all 0.28.0-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+3
  Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (91.189.95.83). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 python-certbot-nginx all 0.28.0-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+3
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-certbot-nginx/python3-certbot-nginx_0.28.0-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+3_all.deb  Could not connect to ppa.launchpad.net:80 (91.189.95.83). - connect (111: Connection refused)

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-certbot-nginx/python-certbot-nginx_0.28.0-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+3_all.deb  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```